# CKEditor convert back to text Symfony 3 and Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, blogs

I created a blog with Symfony and I just include the CKEditor [bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/index.html)

So whenever I tried to write an article I can format it with the bundle and store the article in my database. But when it's store in my database and I try to read it, it doesn't format normaly.

Can somebody help me with this.

This is the rendering of the article from my database with twig
[image: This is the rendering of the article from my database with twig]

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `|raw` will also unescape malicious tags such as `<script>`, you definitely can't use `|raw` if any user can write texts in your rich-text editor.

With your debug console, just make the hidden textarea appear, and fill it with arbitrary code. Disable javascript to remove CKEditor auto-escaping, and see what's going on.

[image]

A better solution is to use [HTMLPurifierBundle](https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle), it will not escape the safe tags such as `<b>`, `<em>`... but will remove untrusted ones such as `<script>`, `<iframe>` etc.

This bundle provides a `|purify` tag, that's the tag to remember.

Comment: thanks for the answer i'll take a look to this bundle !

Answer (score -1):

I do not see your code but I think `raw` [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/escaping.html) solve your problem, some like:

```
{{ article.body|raw }}
```

Comment: No, `|raw` should NEVER be used with user-given content, it's too easy to inject malicious code.

Comment: @lightwalker you'd better use htmlpurifier (https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle) and then use `|purify` instead of `|raw`: it will allow ckeditor html, but filter suspicous tags.

Comment: I supose he get article from database not from user directly. If he get from database the save method escape user input text by default. BUT ALWAYS is better use more security and @Alain answer is more secure (write your answer @Alain)

Comment: now @lightwalker have to change the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys i'll try the @AlainTiemblo solution